# How can I get the mode line to look like the one used in this screen shot?

Tags: mode-line

I've been using powerline, but this doesn't look anything like it.

[image]

and just in case anyone is curious the theme in the picture is this one: https://github.com/emacsfodder/emacs-soothe-theme

Comment: @Dan From looking around I've only seen smart-mode-line and powerline as available packages. I haven't been able to find a screenshot that looks like the one I posted. It makes me wonder if it's a special build of emacs because I've also never seen those little arrows next to the line numbers for collapsing code.

Comment: With a stock version of Emacs -- starting with **Emacs -Q** -- type `M-x describe-variable RET mode-line-format RET` and that will give you the ingredients, which you can then adjust to your liking.  The screen-shot looks fairly basic to me, without much of anything -- it should be very easy to customize.  The value is at the bottom of the help buffer after the description of what the variable is all about.  If you need further help, edit your question and post the contents of the variable and let us know what it is that you want to change.

Comment: The following blog may also be of some assistance in terms of teaching how to customize the `mode-line-format`:  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html